# pdf of sum of squares error

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, density-function, marginal-distribution, sums-of-squares

If $Y_i$ (i=1,...,n) are iid N($\mu$,$\sigma^2$), how would I calculate the marginal pdf of the SSE?

On Wikipedia, I saw that $\sum$($Y_i$-$\bar{Y}$)$^2$ ~ $\sigma^2$$\chi$$^2$(n-1).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, not very easily because of the fact that $\mu$ has to be estimated from the data.  It might be worthwhile as a first step to try to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \mu)^2 \sim \chi^2_n$ .

Comment: Could you add the `self-study` tag and explain what is your difficulty with this standard result? It is covered and established in most Statistics textbooks.

Comment: A proof of the above can be found [here on the maths Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/47013/14893).